# H2 Console can not see tables created by hibernate

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, h2

[image]I have a JEE web project that uses JPA und should run on  JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8). I want to test the project with the in-memory database H2. I deploy my application I see the following on the console:

```
13:55:18,587 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Hibernate: create table seatforshow (id integer not null, isFree boolean not null, price decimal(19,2), rowNo tinyint not null, seatNo tinyint not null, filmShow_id integer not null, primary key (id))

13:55:18,588 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Hibernate: alter table filmshow add constraint FKD4A76E8171BAB7DF foreign key (cinema_id) references cinema

13:55:18,591 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Hibernate: alter table filmshow add constraint FKD4A76E81D7BB783F foreign key (film_id) references film

13:55:18,593 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Hibernate: alter table seat add constraint FK35CE0571BAB7DF foreign key (cinema_id) references cinema

13:55:18,595 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Hibernate: alter table seatforshow add constraint FK5B4E2DA141F8E4BF foreign key (filmShow_id) references filmshow

13:55:18,597 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1

13:55:18,598 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

However, after I open

localhost:8080/h2-console/console/

I do not see my tables there. I suppose that I might need to provide the schema name (or the Database name), but I am not sure. Could somebody help?

Comment: If you are using an in-memory database, then your tables will only be available to you as long as your application is running. Once your application execution completes, tables will get automatically removed from the database because of which you are not able to see any tables

Comment: could you be more specific, please? My application ist still runing on the server, so I assume the tables should still be visible there

Comment: try accessing http://localhost:8080/h2-console/ and give check details provided for schema or else post the screenshot of your h2 DB console

Comment: @Abhijeet see the attached picture above, please

Comment: I think your tables is getting created in a different schema and you are checking in a different schema

Comment: OK, this was also my assumption. But how can I provide the schema I am interested in? Where should I type the name of this schema?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192433/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-alex-mi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the connection URL shown above:
jdbc:h2:~test
this does not match the connectionURL from the file standalone.xml, where the data source is defined.
Once both match, the right Database (and also tables) are shown on the console.